# What are the available packages on Bitnami's stacksmith repository?

Tags: java, docker, apache-spark, bitnami

I am trying to upgrade Java and Scala versions on Bitnami Spark image by updating the Dockerfile:
https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-spark/blob/master/3.3/debian-11/Dockerfile

Going through the rest of the code it looks like it uses below repository URL to download the installation tar files:
https://downloads.bitnami.com/files/stacksmith

I need to find the correct package name with Java 17 and Spark 3.3.0 with Scala 2.13.
How can I view the available packages? Above URL redirect it back to bitnami.com!